# PHP merge JSON with brackets

Tags: php, json, file

I have this JSON file:

```
{"customers": [{"Name": "John Doe", "E-mail": "johndoe@mail.com"}]}
```

And i have this PHP code:

```php
$customers_file = fopen("customers.json", "r");
$customers = json_decode(fread($customers_file ,filesize("customers.json")), true);
fclose($customers_file);

$customer = array("Name" => "Jane Doe", "E-mail" => "janedoe@mail.com");
        
$customers["customers"] += $customer;

$customers_file = fopen("customers.json", "w");
$customers = fwrite($customers_file, json_encode($customers));
fclose($customers_file);
```

Then the JSON file turns in:

```
{"customers": [{"Name": "John Doe", "E-mail": "johndoe@mail.com"}, "Name": "Jane Doe", "E-mail": "janedoe@mail.com"]}
```

Is there a way i can get:

```
{"customers": [{"Name": "John Doe", "E-mail": "johndoe@mail.com"}, {"Name": "Jane Doe", "E-mail": "janedoe@mail.com"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the new item in

```
$customers["customers"] += $customer;
```

this is adding the new array data at the wrong level, you need to add it to the customers array instead (using `[]`)...

```
$customers["customers"][] = $customer;
```

You could also have a look into `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` to reduce the `fopen()`...`fclose()` boilerplate code.

Comment: Thanks! But i have 1 more problem: i get **Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading**